Автоматическая остановка FSM через некоторое время!
В чем суть, я хочу реализовать Автоматическую остановку FSM через какое то время, если пользователь так и не отправил сообщение! Пользователь запускает команду, например  /register где нужно указать свое имя. Пользователь передумав отправлять свое имя, забывает нажать на кнопку отмены. Я хочу что бы если бот так и не получил  сообщение от пользователя за последние  например 10 минут, автоматически останавливал машинное состояние и отправлял пользователю сообщение  о том что тот пользователь не успел! Хочу реализовать это для сохранения и так уж не больших ресурсов бота. Я попросту не представляю как это реализовать. Буду рад если предоставите свой код как вы это реализовали (если вы такое делали) или подскажите как такое можно реализовать)
